# Constructing a function that isn't differentiable at t = 0

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, derivatives

Consider the differentiable function $g \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by
$g(t)=(t,t^3)$.

Construct a function $h \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with the
same image as $g$ such that $g(0)=h(0)$ but $h$ is not differentiable
at $t=0$.

I can't seem to figure this one out. Is anyone able to help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about $h(t) = (\sqrt[3]{t},t)$?

Comment: Yes that works thanks!